# Qt + protobuf, types?

Tags: c++, qt, types, protocol-buffers

I would like to dip into Google's protocol buffers in Qt development, but I am having trouble figuring out how to incorporate them best.

Ultimately, I want to send with `QUdpSocket` and `QTcpSocket` using protocol buffers.

What is the best method for going between a protocol buffer `message` to sending the data over a socket (`QByteArray`) and then back again at the other side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of:

```
std::ostringstream out;
person.SerializeToOstream(&out);
QByteArray byteArray(out.str().c_str());
```

you can also write:

```
QByteArray byteArray(person.SerializeAsString().c_str());
```

EDIT: Above two gives the same result, but I'm not sure wether it's correct. This one seems to work better:

```
QByteArray byteArray(QString::fromStdString(person.SerializeAsString()));
```

EDIT2: OK, now I know how it works: first two ways are wrong if there are \0 char in serialization - everything after it it's then lost. To correct it  one can write:

```
QByteArray byteArray(person.SerializeAsString().c_str(), person.ByteSize());
```

Answer (score 15):

Creating a `QByteArray` from a protobuf object:

```
Person person; // a protobuf object
person.set_id(123);
person.set_name("Bob");
person.set_email("bob@example.com");

std::ostringstream out;
person.SerializeToOstream(&out);
QByteArray byteArray(out.str().c_str());
sendSerializedPersonOverQTcpSocket(byteArray);
```

Reading back a protobuf object from a `QByteArray`:

```
QByteArray byteArray = readSerializedPersonFromQTcpSocket();
Person person;
if (!person.ParseFromArray(byteArray, byteArray.size())) {
  std::cerr << "Failed to parse person.pb." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Not wrong per-se, but you need someway to identify the message on the other side. Plus you need to identify the length of the data. Protobuf does not internally do either of those things.  Also, the stream output version is the slowest of the formatters -- the vector/array outputs are faster.

Comment: I've been trying to use the `SerializeToArray` method, but can't figure out how to do the conversion to `QByteArray`.  Could you give an example of that?

Comment: Please see below for formatted code - i don't know how to format the code in comments. sorry about that. \n\n void convertQByteArrayToUser(QByteArray& aByteArray)
{
    com::your::name_space::User user;
    if(!user.ParseFromArray(aByteArray.data(), aByteArray.size())) {
        //could not parse
    }
    else {
        //yayyyyy
        if(user.has_userid())
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}

Comment: Do not forget to `#include <sstream>` in order to use `std::ostringstream`. However, I would recommend the last approach suggest from @matemaciek

Comment: @Vijay Mathew Where can I find the function sendSerializedPersonOverQTcpSocket ?

Answer (score 6):

Using the code below is really dangerous

```
std::ostringstream out;
person.SerializeToOstream(&out);
QByteArray byteArray(out.str().c_str());
sendSerializedPersonOverQTcpSocket(byteArray);
```

You can find a good explanation here [In protobuf-c, can optional uint32 variable have value 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726495/in-protobuf-c-can-optional-uint32-variable-have-value-0)

A right way to create a QByteArray from a protobuf message is

```
QByteArray byteArray;
byteArray.resize(message.ByteSize());
message.SerializeToArray(byteArray.data(), byteArray.size());
```

Answer (score 3):

@James: You can use `ParseFromArray()`, for example, as below: (Please note that `ParseFromArray()` is available only on proto-buf-lite versions of the libs).

```
void convertQByteArrayToUser(QByteArray& aByteArray)
{
    com::your::name_space::User user;
    if(!user.ParseFromArray(aByteArray.data(), aByteArray.size())) 
    {
        //could not parse
    }
    else { //yayyyyy            
        if(user.has_userid())
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Downvote due to the wrong statement : **available only on proto-buf-lite version of the libs**. Took me two hours to figure out it is available in the full version just as well! Quoating the [Google Light API Documenation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#classes-in-this-file):  `This interface is implemented by all protocol message objects. Non-lite messages additionally implement the Message interface, which is a subclass of MessageLite`