# In protobuf-c, can optional uint32 variable have value 0

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

```
Message Data{
   optional uint64 userid = 1;
   repeated string usernames = 2;
   optional uint32 status = 3;
}
```

**Case 1 - 'status' contains non-zero value'**

If status = non-zero value
When I use the data__pack(const Data * message ,uint8_t * out) function to pack the data, the length of 'out' is 100, and the function returns 100 (The value 100 is used as an example).

**Case 2 - 'status' contains value 0**

If status = 0 (for same values of userid and username as in Case 1)
When I use the data__pack() function to pack the data, the length of 'out' is 99 but the function still returns 100.

If you notice the 2 cases above, if a value of 0 is used for the variable 'status', the length of the output buffer is always 1 less than the length if 'status' would contain a non-zero value. I have set the has_status variable to 1, so that doesn't seem to be an issue.

Is this a protobuf bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Additional details:** Protobuf version I'm using - protobuf-c-0.15

**Additonal details on the issue**

```
Data msg = DATA__INIT;
void* buf = (void*) NULL;
int buf_len = 0;

buf_len = data__get_packed_size(&msg);
buf = (void*) malloc(buf_len+1);

data__pack(&msg, buf);
```

I use data__get_packed_size() to obtain the size. While sending over an HTTP request to the intended receiver, I send a Content-Length of 'buf_len', and 'buf' is used for the HTTP body.

```
Content-Length: 100
Content-Type: application/protobuf

<Body containing the protobuf encoded data - seems to have 99 bytes>
```

The receiver now continues to wait until it receives the complete request (i.e. 100) and  the connection times out eventually. 
In this case, how would the receiver know how to handle this since it would only wait for the Content-Length of 100 to be received?

Comment: I suppose when an optional value is not present, it is taken to be zero.  And so a zero value may as well be omitted during serialization.  Does that explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encoding a `uint32` requires two varints, each of which is at least one byte long. The first byte contains the encoding ("wire") type and the tag number, and will be one byte long if the tag is at most 15. The second varint is the integer itself, which will be one byte long if the integer is at most 127. An omitted ("defaulted") optional field does not occupy any bytes at all; omitted fields are not encoded in any way on the wire; their absence must be deduced.

Consequently, If an optional `uint32` field is omitted, the wire encoding will be at least two bytes shorter than the same protobuf with the optional field included.

You don't indicate how you are computing "the length of 'out'". The *only* correct way is to call `data__get_packed_size` prior to packing the `data` object. I'm guessing, however, that you are using `strlen(out)`, which will *not* produce the correct result. `strlen` can only be used on *strings*; more specifically, it can only be used on `NUL-terminated strings`, because it stops counting when it hits a `NUL` (0) byte, and produces undefined behaviour if it does not see a `NUL` byte. You *must not* use `strlen` on arbitrary binary data.

In the protobuf encoding, an explicit `uint32` with a tag of 3 and a value of 0 will be encoded as `0x18 0x00`, while an explicit `uint32` with a tag of 3 and a value of 42 will be encoded as `0x18 0x2A`. If there were no NULs earlier in the data encoding, then the second byte of the encoding of `0` will terminate `strlen`'s count. Under certain ideal circumstances (say, the buffer is more than long enough, and is cleared to all `NUL`s prior to packing the message into it), `strlen` will report the length of the protobuf with `0` as one "character" shorter than the protobuf with `42`, because the `NUL` in the encoding of the `0` occurs at the end of the message, causing `strlen` to stop counting exactly one byte early.

That's an explanation, not a workaround. *DO NOT* use `strlen` on things which are not NUL-terminated strings.

Comment: You are right. Sorry I did not mention the complete issue. I have added additional details to the problem. Do you have any thoughts on it?

Comment: @cdemon: you still don't explain why you think `out` has only 99 bytes? How are you sending `out` over the HTTP connection? Are you using an API which is only appropriate for strings (i.e., which does not require you to specify the length)?

Comment: When I see the logs at the receiver end, I see that it is waiting for the complete Content-Length to be received. I'm using libevent to send out over the HTTP connection. I see what you're saying, do you think its an issue on the sending side if its only handling strings?

Comment: @cdemon: I absolutely believe that. But you are not providing much detail here. Are you using `libevent`'s simple HTTP server? Afaik, that API requires you to provide an `evbuffer`. So how are you creating the `evbuffer`?

Comment: I need to dig into the legacy code to find that out.. Thanks for you're inputs though. I'll let you know if I find something.